# add filename as text in the corner of an image file

Tags: shell-script, text, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I have a bunch of jpeg images.
Say `001abcd.jpg`,
`002abcd.jpg`,
and so on.

I want to capture the filename and add it as a text in the image itself in one corner.
So the result would be, for example, the file `003abcd.jpg` will have "003abcd" imprinted in one corner of that image. (The extension need not be there.)

I want a terminal command that can batch process hundreds of images and add its own filenames in its respective images.

I am using Linux Mint 17.

Something tells me that imagemagick can be useful, but I don't know scripting.

It is easy to put a single common text in all images. but I don't know how to put unique filenames as the text in the respective images in one go.

Comment: Duplicate (on StackOverflow) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106200/overlaying-an-images-filename-using-imagemagick-or-similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed you can use ImageMagick to write [text](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#escape_chars) into an image. Use the [`convert`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) utility to transform an image to a new file (or `mogrify` to transform a file in place, but I don't recommend it, because if you make a mistake, you lose the original). You specify the text with the [`-annotate`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/option_link.cgi?annotate) option, which can contain [escape sequences](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php) such as `%t` for the file name without directory or extension. There are many more options that let you control the position, size, font, color, etc.

Suppose your files are in a subdirectory called `original` of the current directory. Create a directory `labeled`:

```
mkdir labeled
```

To convert the images, call `convert` like this:

```
convert original/001abcd.jpg -fill green -pointsize 20 -annotate +0+0 %t -gravity north-east labeled/001abcd.jpg
```

The first parameter after `-annotate` is the geometry, which indicates the location of the text. `+0+0` is the corner; the `-gravity north-east` says that this is the top right corner. The second parameter is the text, which here is just the escape sequence that says “use the file name”.

To convert all the `.jpg` files in the directory, write a loop. The wildcard pattern `*.jpg` represents the list of `.jpg` files, to this loop acts on all the `.jpg` files in the `original` directory. In the loop body, `"$x"` refers to the file name with the directory part; `"${x##*/}"` refers to the file name without the directory part.

```
for x in original/*.jpg; do
  convert "$x" original/001abcd.jpg -fill green -pointsize 20 -annotate +0+0 %t -gravity north-east "labeled/${x##*/}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you. It works well. Instead of '-annotate +0+0' I would recommend using '-annotate +2+22' to make text visible and with 2 pixels margin.

Answer (score 13):

`mogrify` does batch processing so you could use something like this (change the font, size, color, position etc as per your taste):

```
mogrify -font Liberation-Sans -fill white -undercolor '#00000080' \
-pointsize 26 -gravity NorthEast -annotate +10+10 %t *.jpg
```

to add the file name without extension (`%t`) to all `jpg`s in the current dir, e.g. `orca-lm-1.jpg`:

[image]

This will overwrite your files so make sure you have backup copies.
If you use a different format (e.g. `png`) for the output files then the original files will remain unchanged:

```
mogrify -format 'png' -font Liberation-Sans -fill white -undercolor \
'#00000080' -pointsize 26 -gravity NorthEast -annotate +10+10 %t *.jpg
```